# Query on capacitor, one large or more in parallel

Tags: capacitor

There is a power line, I need to put decap of 1 \$\mu\$F.

Is it better to use a single 1 \$\mu\$F or three 300 nF capacitors?

Is there any advantage of using three 300nF capacitors?

There is no space or price constraint

Comment: It depends on which types and form factors of capacitors they are. They cannot simply be judged by the capacitance rating. So unless you specify which kind of capacitors the 1uF and the 300nF are, we can't answer that.

Comment: Ceramic capacitor of 0402 pacakage

Comment: 3x 300 nF is not 1 uF.

Comment: And they being ceramic 0402 also is not good enough info. Do you have part numbers and datasheets? Impedance diagrams? ESL, ESR info? Diagram how voltage bias or temperature changes capacitance? And how good performance you even need? Because if both options are good enough, it does not matter which is better in this case if either option is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you define "better" as.

There are a lot of pros and cons to using multiple capacitors versus a single capacitor. I'll try to cover a few.

No capacitor is perfect, there is always an Effective Series Inductance (ESL) and Effective Series Resistance (ESR). So a true capacitor looks something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMUnLi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The values there are just the defaults, not realistic values. Anyway, with frequency the impedance of a capacitor goes down and the impedance of an inductor goes up. Usually the ESL is pretty low, so as you go up in frequency the capacitor dominates and impedance goes down. There is a certain point called the Self Resonant Frequency in which the impedance of the inductor takes over and the impedance starts to go back up.

Usually when you use multiple caps versus a single cap, you vary the value of the cap and even the size of the cap (470n, 330n, 220n at 0402, 0603 and 0805 for example) in order to "shift" the SRF of each individual cap and provide a lower impedance over frequency. Instead of a cusp, you'll have a "flat" area on your Z vs f curve.

This goes for ESR as well. Multiple caps in parallel means that the ESR of the caps combined will usually be less than a single capacitor of equivalent size.

Where this can come back to bite you is that when you have multiple caps, you have longer traces which add in additional inductances. They take up more space which can hurt the routing of other important signals.